# iPhone - Write in app delegate

Tags: iphone, core-data, delegates

i have to write some code that initialize my data app. This must be made before the app the app is loaded. In my opinion the best way is to write this code in app delegate. Am i right?

p.s. : the code download some xml from the net and parse a lot of data and put in core data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YES friend if you write on applicationDidFinishLaunching method in appDelegate ..then webservice get called before the app launch and you have all that data when you start your application . for that you need to set connection by AsiHTTP connection DElegate and parse using NSXmlParserDelegate..

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the exact context you can also implement a [`+ (void)initialize`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/initialize) method in your class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes , its right to call xml parsing in appdelegate so that you had data , before your app first view loads.